# Firebird "insert ... returning" into a variable using stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, insert, firebird

I'm using Firebird 2.x and I have made a stored procedure to insert a record if it doesn't exist and return its ID into a variable.

But when I execute, it turns out that the following error occurs:

```
Dynamic SQL Error. SQL error code = -104. Unexpected end of command - line 2, column 76.
```

Full source code of my SP following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE INSERT_ADMIN_OFFICE
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE OFF_ID BIGINT;
DECLARE VARIABLE PER_ID BIGINT;
DECLARE VARIABLE EMP_ID BIGINT;
DECLARE VARIABLE AP_ID BIGINT;
BEGIN
     IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM OFFICE OFF WHERE OFF.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Administrador%')) THEN
          INSERT INTO OFFICE (DESCRIPTION) VALUES ('Administrador') RETURNING ID INTO :OFF_ID;
     ELSE
          SELECT OFF.ID FROM OFFICE OFF WHERE OFF.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Administrador%' INTO :OFF_ID;

     INSERT INTO PERSON (NAME, BIRTH_DATE, ADDRESS, DISTRICT, CITY, STATE) VALUES ('Intellitools Desenvolvimento de Software Ltda.', '01/01/2007', 'Rua Nunes Machado, 472 - Cj 503', 'Centro', 'Curitiba', 'PR') RETURNING ID INTO :PER_ID;
     INSERT INTO USER_PASSPORT (PERSON_ID, USER_NAME, PWD, TYPE) VALUES (:PER_ID, 'intellitools', 123, 1);
     INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (OFFICE_ID, PERSON_ID) VALUES (:OFF_ID, :PER_ID) RETURNING ID INTO :EMP_ID;
     INSERT INTO ACCESS_PROFILE (DESCRIPTION) VALUES ('Administrador Geral') RETURNING ID INTO :AP_ID;
     INSERT INTO REL_EMPLOYEE_ACCESS_PROFILE (EMPLOYEE_ID, ACCESS_PROFILE_ID) VALUES (:EMP_ID, :AP_ID);
SUSPEND;
END
;
```

I notice that this error is because of the INTO on the INSERT but I can't find another way to do that.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: please, provide full source code of your SP and metadata for OFFICE table.

Comment: Why do you use SUSPEND when your procedure doesn't return any columns?

Comment: SELECT rdb$field_name FROM rdb$relation_fields WHERE rdb$relation_name = 'OFFICE' this query will get you a list of all fields of OFFICE table.

Comment: in fact I don't know, do I have to use it without SUSPEND?

Comment: this select doesn't return anything.

Comment: @AntônioRezendeNeto When exactly do you get the error? When you try to create the stored procedure? Or you already successfully created the stored procedure and you get the error when tring to execute it?

Comment: yes, I successfully created the stored procedure and I get the error when I try to execute it.

Comment: Then show the command how you call the SP - thats what causes the error, the SP itself is OK.

Comment: EXECUTE PROCEDURE INSERT_ADMIN_OFFICE;

Comment: You're executing selectable SP, that's not right... and your SP looks strange too - it doesn't have any parameters, so it is basically for one time use? What are you trying to do?

Comment: yes, it's for one time use and after that it will be dropped

Comment: Is it all done in one script? What tool do you use to create the SP and then execute it?

Comment: I use SQL Manager 2005 for InterBase/Firebird

Comment: But I run it from my C# code as well... same problem

Comment: Just remove SUSPEND and your proc will execute like a charm. For a one time actions I would suggest EXECUTE BLOCK instead of creating stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove SUSPEND and your proc will execute like a charm. For a one time actions I would suggest EXECUTE BLOCK instead of creating stored procedure.